# Can i access the ng-app value in a protractor test?

Tags: angularjs, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I simplified the code i need to test to this:

```
<html ng-app="home" ng-strict-di=""><head>....
```

And i am running some protractor tests, i want to access the value of ng-app so i can compare and see which app is running in each page.

I have tried

```
var appName = element(by.xpath('/html/@ng-app'))
```

but it is not returning a usable promise or text i can compare with

```
appName.getText().then(function(name) {
      expect(name).toBe('home')
      });
```

But protractor complains:

```
InvalidSelectorError: invalid selector: The result of the xpath expression "/html/@ng-app" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
```

So i'm a bit baffled as how can i access my angular app name from protractor to test for app running independently of localization of labels.

Any insight into this enigma?

Answer (score 3):

And it seems like magically, when you order your thoughts to formulate the question, the answer comes to you.

the trick is to get the html as element

```
var appNameHtml = element(by.xpath('/html'))
```

and then, in the test, get the ng-app attribute and use it:

```
appNameHtml.getAttribute('ng-app').then(function(value) {
    expect(value).toBe('home');
});
```

And bingo, you can extract the app name.

Maybe this is a very basic question, but it was driving me insane :)

Answer (score 2):

your answer will suffice I guess in this case. But just wanted to highlight a more generic approach in case `ng-app` may reside not only on `html` element.

`var elementWithNgApp = element(by.css('*[ng-app]'))`

And then wanted to add one more thing. You need not resolve the promise of `getAttribute` to do an expect on its value. `Jasmine` resolves the promise for you. You can have something like this

`expect(elementWithNgApp.getAttribute('ng-app')).toBe('home');`

Comment: Thank you, your answer gave a better understanding of how to handle promises. :)

Comment: Glad that it helped !!